# functions.config().firebase.apiKey is undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that translates text using google translate api. It utilizes this piece of code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

function createTranslateUrl(lang, text) {
  return `https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=${functions.config().firebase.apiKey}&source=en&target=${lang}&q=${text}`;
}
```

The problem is in `functions.config().firebase.apiKey` part. For some time it worked fine but suddenly it started to return `undefined`.

Here's how the config looks like now:

```
  config { firebase: 
   { projectId: 'projectname',
     databaseURL: 'https://projectname.firebaseio.com',
     storageBucket: 'projectname.appspot.com',
     credential: ApplicationDefaultCredential { credential_: MetadataServiceCredential {} } } }
```

I hardcoded the apiKey copying it from firebase console and it works fine for now.

My questions are is it safe to use hardcoded api key? And what might cause `functions.config().firebase.apiKey` to return undefined?

Comment: Why don't you use the Translate node API instead of invoking an HTTP endpoint directly?  It's so much easier.  https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs

Comment: Thanks, @DougStevenson! I'll check it out. Just found the solution above somewhere in google samples for cloud functions. Thought it's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

`firebase.apiKey` was dropped from `functions.config()`

See also this issue on github https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/196

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with this? I'm having exact same issue where `functions.config().firebase.apiKey` is returning `undefined`.

This started happening after my deployment yesterday. I did check [firebase release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) but nothing related to config there.

UPDATE: It turns out there we were using old version of `firebase-functions`. Upgrading to latest version (`0.9.1`) fixed issues.